# How to run a Node.JS app that is forked from github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, github, localhost

Before I say anything else, I am a complete noob to node.js and I just want to see what this web application looks like. I noticed this project at a hackathon and I wanted to test it out. They gave the github repo: https://github.com/android-fanatic/Web But I can't run it from my computer. I understand that I would need to use the command prompt and run it from my local server, but can someone give me step by step directions for installing the node.js app?

Again the link is:
https://github.com/android-fanatic/Web

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)
2. Clone the repository to somewhere on your hard drive
3. Open a command prompt and go to that directory
4. Type `npm install` to install any dependencies
5. Type `npm start`
6. ???
7. PROFIT

The reason you can use `npm start` is because if you look inside of their [package.json](https://github.com/android-fanatic/Web/blob/master/package.json) file you'll see a `"start"` option under `"scripts"`. That command will execute when you type `npm start`.

Comment: I recieved an error when I typed npm install, which said 
`npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058`

Comment: Are you certain you were in the correct directory? Whichever directory the `package.json` resides in, that's where your command prompt needs to be.

Comment: You were right, but when I went to the right directory, this showed up: 
`C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web>npm install
\
> bcrypt@0.8.3 install C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config
_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\.
.\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

Comment: You need to install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for one of those dependencies to work. You'll most likely need version 2.7.10 but if that fails, install the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have node and npm installed on your system, you should be able to do:

```
npm install
npm start
```

The first command will install the node package dependencies and the second will run the server.

Note: I have never used this project, so my guess is based on looking at the repo alone.

The web application should be available at:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: this showed up: 
`C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web>npm install \ > bcrypt@0.8.3 install C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web\node_modules\bcrypt > node-gyp rebuild C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config _node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\. .\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

Comment: And:
`gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Jon Tyler\My Code\Web\node_modules\bcrypt
ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1`